# Why my curl request never stop?

Tags: php, curl

I wanna get 2 years of data while execute php files.
But the problem is, curl request never stop for one occurence, end if i put that :

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
```

It's work but i wait 30sec, in my navigator, i wait few sec for execute the file, why my script never stop?

The code  :

```
<?php
  $dateDeb = '2010-07-23';
  $dateFin = '2012-07-23';

  $debut_mois = 07;
  $debut_jour = 23;
  $debut_annee = 2010;
  $fin_mois = 07;
  $fin_jour = 23;
  $fin_annee = 2012;
$dates=array();
   $debut_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $debut_mois, $debut_jour, $debut_annee);
   $fin_date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $fin_mois, $fin_jour, $fin_annee);

    for($i = $debut_date; $i <= $fin_date; $i+=86400)
    {
            $dates[]=date("Y-m-d",$i);
    }



foreach($dates as $date){

    $cron1='http://ndd.com/admin/api/xiti/bot-lien_sponsorisees/'.$date;
    $cron2='http://ndd.com/admin/api/xiti/bot-affiliation/'.$date;
    $cron3='http://ndd.com/admin/api/xiti/bot-analytics/'.$date;

    echo $date." : EN COURS ... ";

    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cron1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');
   // curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);


    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cron2); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

    echo $date." : OK \n";

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It never stops because your looping through 2 years worth of dates, which is 730 days.

So you are issuing 730 CURL commands, and with the timeout that can equate to 730 * 30 = 21900 max seconds of processing.

Actually I see you are issuing two CURL commands, so 21900 * 2 = 43800 max seconds of processing.

Answer (score 1):

You have two years of days. Each of those will make a *new* request, and new requests don't have any knowledge of old requests or how long those requests took. If you want to stop execution after a certain time, you can use [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php):

```
set_time_limit(30);
```

Comment: Nop, what's i say it's that for the first request it's never stop, but in my navigator, just few seconds, my script never pass to the second request, i dont know why and if i make a timeout, the script stop in 30 sec but if the script finish in 10 sec, its waiting 20 sec for nothing :?

Comment: The script won't finish in ten seconds. At 0.1 seconds per request, you'd still have to wait 73 seconds.

Comment: Yes i know but that i'm saiying, it's the script never Finish the FIRST OCCURENCE.... I can see that because i execute script with my console, the script stop at the first date.

Comment: @Brian There's no guarantee that the server will be flushing output as it generates it.